# How to get rows that have same id on column A on search column B in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
id    Col_A     Col_B
------------------------
1     101       Blue
2     101       Pink
3     102       Orange
4     101       Red
5     103       White
6     102       Black
7     102       yellow
```

now i want to search in Col_B and find all rows that have same id on col_A.

for Example:
    if i search "Pink" return rows 1, 2, 4
    or if i search "Orange" return rows 3,6,7 .

Please help what is MySQL code for this question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (Col_A)
WHERE t2.Col_B = 'needed value'
```